# Access To Message Queue System Denied

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

Hey all,
I'm trying to run the MSMQ+WCF samples at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/msmqpluswcf on Windows 7 and the messages that the client sends with MSMQ don't end up in the queue and no exception is generated.

If I dig through the queue object in debugger after a send, i find the "Access To Message Queue System Denied" but no exception is raised. Also, if I stop MSMQ entirely I still get this message after a send and no exception.

I googled around but with no luck. 
Any ideas? 
If you download the sample and try to run that code is it working for you? (you have to create the MSMQOrders queue)

Thanks in advance,
Serban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Access To Message Queue System Denied" was on the read handler because i was creating the queue in send mode.

The problem was taht the queue was not transactional and on send i was passing the MessageQueueTransactionType.Single parameter.

The removal of MessageQueueTransactionType.Single when calling the send method solved the problem.